# WPF button that sends string to Serial Port

Tags: c#, wpf, string, button, send

Hi there I have a question regarding sending a string that will command an old 80s robot.
I have made the connection to the robot via USB-Serial Port with help from you guys :)

Now I need to assign different strings of code that look like this :":01013100010010"

Every single code controls one of the six step-motors of the robot.

I need help assigning different commands to 6 (I have 6 motors) different "+" and "-" buttons that will control the robot to go for example left or right.

Another I don't know is should I use the "button1_Click" or "button1_MouseDown and up"?
All I need is to click on the button and the robot to go 1 step left or one step right, not all the way it can go to left or right.

Hope you guys can help!

Thanks!

Comment: Bit [1] – ‘:’ – sends a start message to the controller
Bit [ 2,3] – ‘01’ – sets the address to the controller
Bit [ 4,5] – ‘01’ – sets the number of the register
Bit [6] – ‘3’ – sends a request to control motor number ‘3’
Бит [7] – ‘1’ – задава посока на въртене ‘1’ – нагоре, ‘0’ – надолу (посоките “горе” и “долу” са условни)
Bit [ 8-11] – ‘0001’ – sets the type of control of the motor: '0001' – full step, '0002' – half step.
Bit [ 12-15] – ‘0010’ – sets the motor speed which in the case is 10 ms.

Comment: That's what I have from the vendor, so I guess all I need was that with the buttons a different string for each button... ? :/

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the the device your controlling the device would likely need some sort of driver to communicate since it will likely require COM Interop at minimum due to the age

if your trying to hack your way through it your going to have a much more difficult time unless you have the protocol documentation

if you have determined that you can communicate with your BOT then this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8605/Serial-Communication-using-C-and-Whidbey) may help you out

also if there is a compatible driver for it you may want to try out Microsoft Robotics Studio which could help you with some of the cotrol code for your robot, judging from the age it sounds to be a bit unlikely there will be a compatible driver for it tho

Comment: Hi there, I don't really need a driver I can send commands like the example I gave trough hyper terminal and the BOT executes them all so I think that's all I need ?

Comment: in that case you should be able to use the SerialPort class to facilitate communication I believe,  using _serialPort.WriteLine() to send your commands

Comment: you can try http://www.nuget.org/packages/PInvokeSerialPort/1.0.0 as well if you are running into problems using the SerialPort Class