# C# WPF Serial port communication convert?

Tags: c#, string, serial-port

Hi there I'm a complete newbie and I'm asking dumb questions, so thanks for the time...

I'm trying to send a command that is a string to a device I have - "Robot" that I control via USB -> Serial Port. This string should look like that :01013100010010 and it should tell a certain step motor to make a specific amount of steps. Every time i try to send that string like that :01013100010010 it doesn't do anything, but if I open Hyper Terminal and send it like that it does the command.

Do I need to convert it to something special or the problem is something else ?

Another thing is how can I assign the string ":01013100010010" to be sent when a button is pressed so if someone can show me a sample code of how to do that i.e. send the data on button click I would be grateful !

Here is the code I have for now it's a simple UI :

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM2";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
            serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            serialPort1.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
            serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 500;
            serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 500;
            serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
            serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
            serialPort1.Open();

            richTextBox1.Text = "Connected";
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(serialPort1.IsOpen){
            string text = richTextBox1.Text;
                serialPort1.WriteLine(text);}
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what code are you using?

Comment: Hi there I'm using C# I have made the UI in a WPF program all I need to do now is add functionality.

Comment: your question then makes no sense. you say that "Everytime I try to send that string like that...it doesn't do anything". well, what code are you using to send that string?!

Comment: Wanna show us the code that doesn't work so we can try to fix it?

Comment: I've made a UI that have a init button that opens the COM port, then I have a text box in which I put the :01013100010010 and last I have a send button that sends the command to the COM port. I'm sorry my question is not the best...

Comment: @Vlad I just added it

Comment: First thing I noticed is that you are using `serialPort1.WriteLine`. `WriteLine` will include the newline character which your hardware may or may not be expecting. Even if it is expecting a newline, you might want to check it expects the same newline character that you are sending (See the `SerialPort.NewLine` property).

Comment: It sounds like there is a difference between what hyper term sends as a newline, probably CRLF, and what the code is sending.  The NewLine property of the serialport defaults to LF.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF button that sends string to Serial Port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640442/wpf-button-that-sends-string-to-serial-port)

Comment: MattBurland I will look in to that I don't really think that my hardware is expecting a newline. I will check that , thanks!

@dbasnett Yes that's exactly what I was thinking. As far as I know every command I need to send should end with \r\n for example :01013100010010\r\n but I have used the code without the \r\n and it was working ok

Comment: Well that's your problem then. The default for [SerialPort.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) is just the line feed character. Not line feed / carriage return.

Comment: Nothing WPF related in this question, removing the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write on the SerialPort. to do that, use something like this

```
        serialPort1.Open();
        serialPort1.Write(@":01013100010010");
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        serialPort1.Close();
```

I´m using Thread.Sleep on the code because in my work sometimes our device don´t receive the full command if we just write and then close the port.

@edit: Sample code working on client

```
portaserial = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
portaserial.Open();
portaserial.Write(mensagem.ToString());
Thread.Sleep(500);
portaserial.Close();
```

Source: myself

Comment: Thanks Marciano, will take a notice :)

Comment: You can try serialPort1.Flush();

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
serialPort1.NewLine = "\r\n";
```